# Swift How to Add a 5-Star-Rating Option for Users

Tags: swift, database, server, user-controls, rating

I'm creating an app that allows users to vote for products from 1 to 5 star ratings, then calculates the average rating of that product by taking the average vote of all the users.(just like Zomato) My app won't need a user to login, it only needs the users' votes and they can add comments. Is there a way to do this without creating a server like using FireBase?

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

No. You need one central place to gather data and do calculations.